# Though variables have been initialized I get might not have been initialized error

Tags: java, android

I am having problem with the following code in an android app that I am developing. Now even though I have initialized the variables I am getting the error variable might not have been initialized.

```
Activity context;
context = new Activity();
SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem;
try {
    InputStream configAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("MyConfig.cfg");
    try {
        alizeSystem = new SimpleSpkDetSystem(configAsset, context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath());
    } catch (AlizeException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
    }
    configAsset.close();

} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
InputStream backgroundModelAsset;
try {
    backgroundModelAsset = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("gmm/world.gmm");
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
try {
    alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
} catch (AlizeException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
try {
    backgroundModelAsset.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
```

The following are the errors I am getting

```
Error:(274, 13) error: variable alizeSystem might not have been initialized
Error:(274, 45) error: variable backgroundModelAsset might not have been initialized
Error:(279, 9) error: variable backgroundModelAsset might not have been initialized
Error:(274, 44) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: this is what you can get, if your variables are not initialized for every possible flow. for instance, if you initialize a variable within an if-block, remember, that if-condition can return false. The same for try-blocks in your case, it might throw an Exception, leaving the variable as not-initialized.

Answer (score 3):

> Now even though I have initialized the variables

You haven't though - not necessarily. Suppose the `new SimpleSpkDetSystem(...)` call throws an `AlizeException`. You're catching that exception and continuing - but you won't have assigned a value to `alizeSystem`. The same is true for all the other variables.

I suspect the solution here is *not* to just log exceptions and then continue as if they hadn't happened, but instead let them bubble up to the caller.

Comment: But I am having problem with exception in this line  alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);. If I declared the exception as IOexception in the catch block I get alizeexception error but if I declare it as Alizeexception I get IOexception as error

Comment: @threewire: Yes, you'll have the same problem multiple times, because every time an exception is thrown your "handling" is basically "Just log it and keep going" which doesn't work when you need the result of one step in order to perform later steps.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are initializing the variable inside a try catch block

Use the following:-

```
SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = null;
```

Initialise every variable in similar way to some value whenever you are declaring them, specially those which are being initialised or created in some try catch or if blocks.

Comment: a better way would be to have the next statements in the same try block as the initialization. your suggestion might lead to a NullPointerException

Comment: It depends on the try catch Exception class @Stultuske, that which exception we are catching.

Comment: no, it wouldn't. in the first try block, it would fail, hence in the second block, you would get: [null].loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
catching it doesn't mean it won't occur

Answer (score 2):

The variables are not initialized, as the error correctly states.

In your code you have:

```
SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem;
```

This mean you are not initializing the variable alizeSystem. Then you assign a value to it, but inside a try/catch block: if some exception is thrown, the variable will not be initialized. 
Finally, you perform this:

```
alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
```

but if the first try/catch block catches an exception, alizeSystem is not initialized. So you just have to initialize it to null when you define it:

```
SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = null;
```

and check for null-value when you use it:

```
if(alizeSystem!=null)
    alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
```

The same goes for all the other unitialized variables

Comment: Putting it to null fixed it. But I am having problem with exception. If I declared the exception as IOexception I get alizeexception error but if I declare it as Alizeexception I get IOexception as error

Comment: I see you have nested try/catch blocks. I suggest you don't use them. Better stick to a flat try block, and use multiple catches. then you can catch any exception, of any type, that the try block could throw

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide value for these variables, because during execution program continues to run even when excepton is thrown. In your case I think you need to stop execution of this code block after logging error

Answer (score 0):

You should trying:

```
    SimpleSpkDetSystem alizeSystem = null;
```

Then

```
try {
     alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
}catch (AlizeException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File not found for recording ", e);
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Null alizeSystem ", e);
}
```